# How to implement One-Vs-Rest for Multi-Class Classification in Julia?

Tags: database, dataframe, julia

I’m new to Julia and i am trying to implement One-Vs-Rest Multi-Class Classification, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Here is a snippet of my code so far:
My data frame is basic since I’m trying to figure out the implementation first, my c column is my class consisting of [0, 1, 2], and my y, x1, x2, x3 are random Int64 values.

```
using DataFrames
using CSV

using StatsBase

using StatsModels

using Statistics

using Plots, StatsPlots

using GLM

using Lathe

df = DataFrame(CSV.File(“data.csv”))

fm = @formula(c~x1+x2+x3+y)

model0 = glm(fm0, df, Binomial(), ProbitLink()) # 0 vs [1,2]
model1 = glm(fm1, df, Binomial(), ProbitLink()) # 1 vs [0,2]
model2 = glm(fm2, df, Binomial(), ProbitLink()) # 2 vs [0,1]
```

I am trying to make logistic models but I don’t know how to do it.
If anyone can help me out, I would be thrilled.

I am trying to split the multi-class dataset into multiple binary classification problems. A binary classifier is then trained on each binary classification problem and predictions are made using the model that is the most confident.
My only problem is that I don't how to write the logistic model for a multi-class dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do the same manually using GLM.jl (there is a lot of boilerplate code, but I wanted to keep the example simple):

```
df = DataFrame(x1=rand(100), x2=rand(100), x3=rand(100), target=rand([0, 1, 2], 100));
model0 = glm(@formula((target==0)~x1+x2+x3), df, Binomial(), ProbitLink())
model1 = glm(@formula((target==1)~x1+x2+x3), df, Binomial(), ProbitLink())
model2 = glm(@formula((target==2)~x1+x2+x3), df, Binomial(), ProbitLink())
choice = argmax.(eachrow([predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)])) .- 1 # need to subtract 1 to use 0-based indexing
```

Let me explain the last operation step by step:

1. get the predictions of three models as columns of a matrix

```
julia> [predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)]
100×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.517606   0.314234  0.206062
 0.173916   0.431573  0.389071
 0.211322   0.355592  0.413929
 0.252108   0.337381  0.387629
 0.515388   0.306834  0.211937
 0.169052   0.386062  0.436603
 0.125764   0.395105  0.490297
 0.0955411  0.347634  0.589351
 0.449734   0.341201  0.227459
 ⋮
 0.412786   0.281343  0.303454
 0.209337   0.354169  0.417261
 0.37683    0.345307  0.273704
 0.187584   0.411171  0.390831
 0.401612   0.243119  0.350124
 0.323155   0.338805  0.322453
 0.488678   0.300927  0.23324
 0.0979282  0.413296  0.522639
 0.195902   0.313932  0.472582
```

2. Iterate rows of this matrix:

```
julia> eachrow([predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)])
Base.Generator{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.var"#240#241"{Matrix{Float64}}}(Base.var"#240#241"{Matrix{Float64}}([0.5176063824396965 0.3142344514631397 0.2060615429588215; 0.17391563070921184 0.4315728844478078 0.3890711795309746; … ; 0.09792824142064335 0.41329629745776897 0.5226385962610233; 0.19590183503978997 0.31393218775269705 0.4725817014561341]), Base.OneTo(100))
```

3. For each row get index of maximum value:

```
julia> argmax.(eachrow([predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)]))
100-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 3
 1
 3
 3
 3
 1
 ⋮
 1
 3
 1
 2
 1
 2
 1
 3
 3
```

4. Subtract 1 from the result as Julia uses 1-based indexing, and you wanted the first model to have number 0:

```
julia> argmax.(eachrow([predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)])) .- 1
100-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1
 2
 2
 0
 2
 2
 2
 0
 ⋮
 0
 2
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
 2
 2
```

Alternatively you could write:

```
julia> map(predict(model0), predict(model1), predict(model2)) do x...
           return argmax(x) - 1
       end
100-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1
 2
 2
 0
 2
 2
 2
 0
 ⋮
 0
 2
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
 2
 2
```

Which is more efficient and shorter, but I was not sure if it is clearer as it uses [slurping](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#The-two-uses-of-the-...-operator:-slurping-and-splatting).

---

An example how to train one model for three classes using Flux.jl (still using the same `df` source data frame):

```
using Flux
model = Chain(Dense(3 => 3, σ), softmax)
X = permutedims(Matrix(df[:, 1:3]))
y = Flux.onehotbatch(df.target, 0:2)
optim = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(0.01), model)
for epoch in 1:1_000
    Flux.train!(model, [(X, y)], optim) do m, x, y
        y_hat = m(x)
        Flux.crossentropy(y_hat, y)
    end
end
```

Comment: What does the line ```choice = argmax.(eachrow([predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)])) .- 1``` mean? By the way, I am very grateful for yours and Shayan's help.

Comment: I have added an additional explanation.

Comment: I was wondering, since x1, x2 and x3 can belong to any of the three classes, how do I find out the probability of which class the data belongs to? For an example there are 3 classes[C1, C2, C3] in which a single data can belong to. We should get the probability from the logistic regression that the data belongs(for an example) 20% to C1, 35% to C2, and 45% to C3, then the algorithm chooses the class with the highest probability. This is my current dilemma. Thank you for all your time, I am very grateful.

Comment: You asked for OvR models - so the probabilities produced by individual models do not need to add up to 1. You can do two things: one is to manually normalize the sum of probabilities to 1, the other is to build a joint model that guarantees that probabilities add to 1 by design. I give you an example how to do it using Flux.jl in the edit.

Comment: How can I manually do it? Since I have never used Flux.jl and I don't understand 95% of it

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"? Do you mean to make GLM predictions add up to one? Then do `p = [predict(model0) predict(model1) predict(model2)]` and next `p ./ sum(p, dims=2)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250704/discussion-between-skalarr-and-bogumil-kaminski).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I choose the Julia implementation for it. So [Bogumił Kamiński's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74933045/11747148) would be superior to mine.
I don't know if any packages provide a multi-target/label *Logistic Regression* model implemented fully in Julia (I would like to know if there are any, I'll **prepend** them to this answer). But, you can apply the model using `ScikitLearn.jl` which is a wrapper for Scikit-learn in Python and uses a connected python session to run the code. You can get further information in their [repository](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl). But, I created synthetic data as similar as I could to what you have to train the model on it and show you how you can do it:

```
#- Packages
using DataFrames
using ScikitLearn
@sk_import linear_model: LogisticRegression

#- Syntethetic data
df = DataFrame(
  x1=rand(100),
  x2=rand(100),
  x3=rand(100),
  target=rand([0, 1, 2], 100)
)
# 100×4 DataFrame
#  Row │ x1          x2         x3         target
#      │ Float64     Float64    Float64    Int64
# ─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────
#    1 │ 0.607024    0.6818     0.562058        0
#    2 │ 0.235538    0.974469   0.553292        1
#    ⋮ │     ⋮           ⋮           ⋮            ⋮
#   99 │ 0.382491    0.224192   0.122515        1
#  100 │ 0.617425    0.793276   0.228549        0

#- Split data
train, test = df[1:80, :], df[81:end, :]
```

Then I train the `LogisticRegresssion` (which inherently runs the same object in the sklearn.py):

```
#- Train model
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class="ovr")
fit!(model, Matrix(train[:, 1:3]), train[:, 4])
```

And the last phase would be the prediction:

```
#- Predict
preds = predict(model, Matrix(test[:, 1:3]));

#- Count right predictions
sum(preds .== test[:, 4])
# returns `6` in my case
```

Note that you need to install [`PyCall.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) to use `ScikitLearn.jl`. Make sure to follow the instructions provided by the `PyCall.jl` to set up the required environment first.

Comment: I downloaded all of the libraries, but when I run it, it says that fit!() is not defined

Comment: To estimate OvR model in ScikitLearn you need to use `LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr')`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, Thanks dear professor. I missed that part. I'll add it.

Comment: @skalarr, have you googled the error?